# Co occurance matrix for tfidf vectorizer for top 2000 words

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, similarity, tfidfvectorizer

i computed tfidf vectorizer for text data and got vectors as (100000,2000) max_feature = 2000.

while i am computing the co occurance matrix by below code.

```
length = 2000
m = np.zeros([length,length]) # n is the count of all words
def cal_occ(sentence,m):
    for i,word in enumerate(sentence):
    print(i)
    print(word)
    for j in range(max(i-window,0),min(i+window,length)):
        print(j)
        print(sentence[j])
        m[word,sentence[j]]+=1
for sentence in tf_vec:
    cal_occ(sentence, m)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
0
(0, 1210)   0.20426932204609685
(0, 191)    0.23516811545499153
(0, 592)    0.2537746177804585
(0, 1927)   0.2896119458034052
(0, 1200)   0.1624114163299802
(0, 1856)   0.24376566018277918
(0, 1325)   0.2789314085220367
(0, 756)    0.15365704375851477
(0, 1130)   0.293489555928974
(0, 346)    0.21231046306681553
(0, 557)    0.2036759579760878
(0, 1036)   0.29666992324872365
(0, 264)    0.36435609585838674
(0, 1701)   0.242619998334931
(0, 1939)   0.33934107208095693
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-ad505b6df734> in <module>()
 11             m[word,sentence[j]]+=1
 12 for sentence in tf_vec:
 ---> 13     cal_occ(sentence, m)

 <ipython-input-96-ad505b6df734> in cal_occ(sentence, m)
  9             print(j)
 10             print(sentence[j])
 ---> 11             m[word,sentence[j]]+=1
 12 for sentence in tf_vec:
 13     cal_occ(sentence, m)
```

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Answer (score 0):

You are having the problem most probably here:

```
for j in range(max(i-window,0),min(i+window,length)):
```

*min* function returns length when *i+window* exceeds the bound, can you try this instead of the line above:

```
for j in range(max(i-window,0),min(i+window,length-1)):
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers

Comment: Hi berking thanks for the response, but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: Hi ravi, then the only case I could see here is i+window happens to be lower than length and trying to access sentence[i+window] causes exception. Did you mean to use the length of sentences instead of constant length above? In any case can you use for j in range(max(i-window,0),min(i,length)): ? Cheers.